# Loading Google script in React Component

Tags: meteor, reactjs, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, meteor-react

I'm trying to access the YouTube Data API v3, but I'm having some trouble figuring out how to load the script in React. `this.init()` fires, but I get `gapi = {}`. Oddly enough when i enter `gapi` in the console, it shows up as the appropriate object.

```
TestPage = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    $.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/client.js", this.handleClientLoad);
  },

  handleClientLoad(data, textStatus) {
    Utils.logObj(data, "data");
    Utils.logObj(textStatus, "textStatus");
    Utils.logObj(gapi, "gapi");
    Utils.logObj(window.gapi, "window.gapi");
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>This is the test page.</div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine check the console: http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/ocpz7pbm/

```
var App = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    $.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/client.js", this.handleClientLoad);
  },

  handleClientLoad() {
    console.log(window.gapi);
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>This is the test page.</div>
    );
  }
});
```

Perhaps your `Utils.logObj` is not working as expected?

Comment: I double checked this, the log isn't the problem... The object isn't there.